# Is it possible to lower the privilege level when calling CoCreateInstance on Vista?

Tags: c++, com, windows-vista, uac

Okay, I have a plugin for IE that when installed needs to (with the user's permission) restart IE.

To do this I have a DLL that is invoked by the installer. And it works, but the problem is that when IE is restarted on Vista, it is restarted with the administrator privileges of the installer, which is a problem for a number of reasons.

I'm using CoCreateInstance to start IE, so that I get an instance of the IWebBrowser2 interface in order to perform some actions on it.

So my question is, is it possible to call CoCreateInstance from an application that is running with Administrator privileges, in such a way that the resulting COM object instance inherits the base user privileges rather than the administrator privileges of the calling application?

Comment: Are you aware of SetThreadToken() that can impersonate a thread as another user?

Comment: As usually happens, I just came across some information about this right after I posted this question, and SetThreadToken seems to be part of the solution. I'm going to give it a try now and see if it works for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution from here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/cs-CZ/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/78a2bc18-1920-4e58-af7e-48dbcebe7643

From my installer DLL I need to launch a new thread, and impersonate the current user on that thread, and then set a low integrity level, and create the COM instance with the CLSCTX_ENABLE_CLOAKING context.

Comment: Are you sure you can repost content from other sites here?

Comment: I'd be careful trying to marshal the interface pointer back from that thread -- stubs are bound to the apartment they were created in, and when you call CoUninitialize(), the apartment is killed, and your IWebBrowser2 stub too. You probably need to keep the thread/apartment alive for as long as the interface pointer is used.

Comment: @sharptooth, good point, I deleted the content and just left the link to the other site.