# Register COM server to always run in low privilege level

Tags: process, com, registry

I am working on a feasibility task, where a COM server (WPF app) is launched using `CoCreateInstance()` from an MFC application.

However, the integrity level of the COM server is same as that of the MFC app from which it is called.

I need the COM server to run in low/medium integrity level even if the MFC app runs in high integrity level. (i.e. the COM server should never run in high integrity level in any case)

According to this link [Is it possible to lower the privilege level when calling CoCreateInstance() on Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1304847/18109256), I need to launch a new thread, impersonate the current user on that thread, and set a low integrity level, and then call `CoCreateInstance()`.

Is there an alternative to this method where the COM server registration can be modified so that `CoCreateInstance()` always launches the COM server in low/medium integrity level irrespective of the launcher MFC app's medium/high integrity level?

Comment: The another thread "trick" would let anyone else calling it directly from its level. Are you looking for runas : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/setting-processwide-security https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/runas